# Asp.net core 3.0 how to register custom model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to register a custom model binder in ASP.NET Core 3.0 `startup.cs` based on the following examples:

[Link 1](https://dev.to/usmanuzi/how-to-bind-model-value-frombody-by-custom-binder-in-asp-net-core-32ik)

[Link 2](http://www.prasannapattam.com/2016/12/aspnet-core-custom-frombody-model.html)

The code below is not working, can someone please help - thanks!

```
 services.AddMvc()
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        IHttpRequestStreamReaderFactory readerFactory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHttpRequestStreamReaderFactory>();
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new NtBodyModelBinderProvider(options.InputFormatters, readerFactory));
    });
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the application:

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IModelBinderProvider Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: CustomerCash.External.Api.ModelBinders.NtBodyModelBinderProvider': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.IInputFormatter]' while attempting to activate 'CustomerCash.External.Api.ModelBinders.NtBodyModelBinderProvider'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IModelBinder Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: CustomerCash.External.Api.ModelBinders.NtBodyModelBinder': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.IInputFormatter]' while attempting to activate 'CustomerCash.External.Api.ModelBinders.NtBodyModelBinder'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at CustomerCash.External.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Development\JamesHay\jhcode\CustomerCashExternal\src\CustomerCash.External.Api\Program.cs:line 11
```

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
Inner Exception 1:

```
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor '
ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IModelBinderProvider
Lifetime: Scoped
ImplementationType: CustomerCash.External.Api.ModelBinders.NtBodyModelBinderProvider':
 Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.IInputFormatter]' while attempting to activate 'CustomerCash.External.Api.ModelBinders.NtBodyModelBinderProvider'.
```

Inner Exception 2:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.IInputFormatter]' while attempting to activate 'CustomerCash.External.Api.ModelBinders.NtBodyModelBinderProvider'.
```

Comment: Hi Aluan, just added the exception thrown when running the application. It's complianing about how NtBodyModelBinderProvider.cs is registered in Startup.cs

Comment: Looks like your provider is registered somewhere else

Comment: I've copied the code as is from this link: http://www.prasannapattam.com/2016/12/aspnet-core-custom-frombody-model.html  I believe how you should be registering NtBodyModelBinderProvider.cs in Startup.cs has changed in asp.net core 3.0. I don't know how to fix the issue hence I'm asking for help.

Comment: options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new NtBodyModelBinderProvider()); This is how you would register the provider if it's constractor was parameterless, but in this case we're passing two parameter values to the constructor.

Comment: I don't know if that example is applicable to 3.1 but regardless, `services.BuildServiceProvider()` is very problematic code. The official document examples that are closest to the code that you're writing do not create a separate service provider or use the service provider at all.

Comment: Sorry Aluan, excuse me for my ignorance, how can I write the same code without using services.BuildServiceProvider() ? thanks!

Comment: services.AddMvc()
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        IHttpRequestStreamReaderFactory readerFactory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHttpRequestStreamReaderFactory>();
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new NtBodyModelBinderProvider(options.InputFormatters, readerFactory));
    });